# How to grant ACL in Spring Security without an explicit authentication?

Tags: spring-security, acl

When I create a new entity I would like to grant ACL permissions (aka ACL entry) to this new entity. So far so easy :-)

The problem arises in the following scenario:

- An end user can create the entity without being authenticated on the web site.
- The service that persists this new entity hence runs without an authentication context.
- But: to grant ACEs one needs to have an active authentication context.

Spring's `JdbcMutableAclService` uses `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to obtain the current authentication, so there seems to be no way to circumvent this requirement.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

In a web application there *always* is an authentication context. If a user is not authenticated the authentication is `org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken` which has a single granted authority: `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`.

Hence it is simple to grant this user the right to create ACLs. Just configure the `PermissionGrantingStrategy` to use this role to authorize requests.

Comment: I tried this and it his doesn't work.